# Why can't I edit a field outside of a specific function (javascript/html)?

Tags: javascript, html

((This is part of a homework assignment but I am not asking for anyone to tell me what exactly to write, so hang in there I think this will be simple to answer))

I have a script that simulates a game of craps. I'm going to post it at the end but read the rest of the question first, as most of the code is not pertinent to my issue.

My job is to implement a bank and wager system. Sounds easy enough but I got stuck. So my first move was to make a column for bank in the result table. Next I put this code in the play() function:

```
bank = prompt("How much money is in your bank?");
document.getElementById( "bankfield" ).value = bank;
```

Run script, press button that calls play(), window pops up, enter value, field changes. So far so good. But the I realize that I dont want that code in there because the bank should not be reset every time the dice are rolled. So I cut and paste thoes two lines right to the beginning of the script so it is the first thing that happens when it is run. **But**... now after I am prompted and enter a value, the bankfield stays empty and I get    [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwyJ6.png):

Why do these two lines work just fine in the play() function but not openly in the script?

I have been messing around with this for a long time but I'm not making progress I think I'm missing a concept here, and was thinking someone here could enlighten me.Thanks!

Here is the original game script for refence:

```
      </style>
  <script type = "text/javascript">

     // variables used to test the state of the game
     var WON = 0;
     var LOST = 1;
     var CONTINUE_ROLLING = 2;

     // other variables used in program
     var firstRoll = true; // true if current roll is first
     var sumOfDice = 0; // sum of the dice
     var myPoint = 0; // point if no win/loss on first roll
     var gameStatus = CONTINUE_ROLLING; // game not over yet

     // process one roll of the dice
     function play()
     {
        // get the point field on the page
        var point = document.getElementById( "pointfield" );

        // get the status div on the page
        var statusDiv = document.getElementById( "status" );
        if ( firstRoll ) // first roll of the dice
        {
           sumOfDice = rollDice();

           switch ( sumOfDice )
           {
              case 7: case 11: // win on first roll
                 gameStatus = WON;
                 // clear point field
                 point.value = "";
                 break;
              case 2: case 3: case 12: // lose on first roll
                 gameStatus = LOST;
                 // clear point field
                 point.value = "";
                 break;
              default: // remember point
                 gameStatus = CONTINUE_ROLLING;
                 myPoint = sumOfDice;
                 point.value = myPoint;
                 firstRoll = false;
           } // end switch
        } // end if
        else 
        {
           sumOfDice = rollDice();

           if ( sumOfDice == myPoint ) // win by making point
              gameStatus = WON;
           else
              if ( sumOfDice == 7 )    // lose by rolling 7
                 gameStatus = LOST;
        } // end else

        if ( gameStatus == CONTINUE_ROLLING )
           statusDiv.innerHTML = "Roll again";
        else 
        {
           if ( gameStatus == WON )
              statusDiv.innerHTML = "Player wins. " +
                 "Click Roll Dice to play again.";   
           else 
              statusDiv.innerHTML = "Player loses. " + 
                 "Click Roll Dice to play again.";     

           firstRoll = true;
        } // end else
     } // end function play

     // roll the dice
     function rollDice()
     {
        var die1;
        var die2;
        var workSum;

        die1 = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 6 );
        die2 = Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 6 );
        workSum = die1 + die2;

        document.getElementById( "die1field" ).value = die1; 
        document.getElementById( "die2field" ).value = die2;
        document.getElementById( "sumfield" ).value = workSum;

        return workSum;
     } // end function rollDice
     // 
  </script>
```

I'm very new to JS and cs rookie in general so be gentle. Also my first question asked here so sorry if I have bad formating or whatever.

Comment: Move `<script>` to the end of your html file

Answer (score 0):

It most likely is referring to 'point.value' and means that 'point' doesn't exist.  Looking a few lines earlier you are declaring it, but that line is probably not finding it.

Make sure your script is running AFTER the document is finished loading before scanning for HTML elements.